# Applying Inception but get the Attribute Error:

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Here I was trying to run the Inception method but then I got the error message ---

My code is as below ---

```
from IPython.display import Image, display
Image('images/07_inception_flowchart.png')
         
# Classes and functions for loading and using the Inception model
import inception
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf

tf.__version__

# Download the Inception model
inception.data_dir = 'inception/'

def maybe_download():
    """
    Download the Inception model from the internet if it does not already
    exist in the data_dir. The file is about 85 MB.
    """

    print("Downloading Inception v3 Model ...")
    download.maybe_download_and_extract(url=data_url, download_dir=data_dir)

inception.maybe_download()
```

---

but got the error message ---

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a941731aed67> in <module>()
----> 1 inception.maybe_download()

AttributeError: module 'inception' has no attribute 'maybe_download'
```

---

Please help me as soon as possible

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to run the inception model from Tensorflow, right? The `inception` model which you would `import` in Python like you did, is quite old.
In general your `AttributeError: module ... has not attribute ...` states that the method you want to call on your object/module is not existant. In your specific case, that means that `maybe_download()` is not a method of the inception object/module. However, since I assume you want to use tensorflows' `inception` method, check out [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/inception.py) repo. It has detailled explanation on how to use the `maybe_download` method for the inception model and how to get started.

**EDIT:**

Alright, now I understood your problem (at least I hope so). In your first line of code you `pip install inception`. As I assume you are trying to do the [Tensorflow-Tutorials](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials). In that case `inception` does not refer to a package which can be installed via `pip` rather it refers to a `module` within the given repository. A `module` in that sense is another `.py` script. If you go to the referenced [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials) you can search for a file named `inception.py`. Within that file you can also find the `maybe_download()` function.

In terms of code:
First go to a folder and do:

`git clone https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials.git`

Once you have done that you can create your own `.py` with your inception model within the same folder as the repo. Then you can easily `import inception` in your `.py` file and it should work. For a more detailled code example please review [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/07_Inception_Model.ipynb) notebook. Please remember in order to run it locally to clone the repository as described above with `git clone`.

Comment: I know your comment but I cannot understand how to solve the problem --- please write some coding in order to solve the above error

Comment: I rewrite my code but still get the same error --- can I use another code to download the inception model because of this method cannot successful when I am using it in the google colab